# sharepoint package setup

Tags: sharepoint, installation, package

i am new to sharepoint. i have a sharepoint application. i have to create a package setup (install shield kind of thing) that can deploy the sharepoint solution on the client machine. in my application we have .dll,.ascx,.xml etc files available. i think i have to deploy the dlls,ascx, xml files.

Can any body help me on this? how shloud i go forward and is there any tool available which i can use for this?

is it possible with VS2005? VS2005 provides a setup and deploy feature. can we use that for sharepoint? if yes can any body help me how to do it?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Try and have a look at http://www.codeplex.com/sharepointinstaller. It is a free tool offering a user friendly install/upgrade/uninstall of SharePoint solutions.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you need to understand is Solution Packages. They are the unit of  deployment in SharePoint.

[Creating a Solution Package in Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb466225.aspx)

However, Solution Packages are meant to be deployed by SharePoint Administrators. They don't have a user friendly installation process.

If you want something more like an installer, you can look at the [SharePoint Solution Installer CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/sharepointinstaller) project.